# The tags [cv2] and [opencv-python] mean the same thing

Tags: discussion, tags

There are two tags that mean the same thing: [cv2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cv2) and [opencv-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opencv-python). They are both used to indicate that the question is related to the Python bindings for the OpenCV library. They are both very small tags, 664 and 128 questions, respectively.

There are currently [11,749 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opencv+python) tagged with both [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) and [opencv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opencv), I am not even sure we need a special tag for the OpenCV bindings at all. But if there is a place for such a tag, it should be just one, not two.

- **Option 1:** Should we make these synonyms? Few people have sufficient points in either of these tags to make the synonym. I think a moderator needs to do this.
- **Option 2:** Should we get rid of these two tags altogether, and replace them with [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) and [opencv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opencv)?

Benefits of Option 2: People follow the [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) and [opencv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opencv) tags, so if you want your question answered, you need to add those two tags to your question anyway. Once the question has these tags added, the [cv2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cv2) or [opencv-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opencv-python) doesn't add any information.

Note that of the 664 questions [cv2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cv2), 509 also have [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python), and 322 also have [opencv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opencv).

Comment: [tag:opencv-python] doesn't make much sense. We also don't have specific tags for other libraries that support multiple languages (no [tag:opengl-python], e.g.). I can't tell if [tag:cv2] is needed. Is cv2 just a binding or does it provide any functionality above opencv?

Comment: While at it, it would make sense to cleanup the whole OpenCV tag system. There is also [tag:opencv4android], [tag:opencv4ios], [tag:opencv-ios], [tag:opencvdotnet], [tag:opencvsharp], [tag:opencv4nodejs] (Description: " Now we just need an OpenCV expert to judge which of them make sense and which don't.

Comment: BDL: Looking at [the source code](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/tree/master/modules/python) it’s clear that cv2 is no more than a thin wrapper. The only Python code there is a program that generates the wrapper code. — Yes, the OpenCV tags are a mess. Last night I did retag all three [opencv-ios] questions to [opencv4ios], which had a few more Qs. But again, if you tag a question with [ios] and [opencv], what does [opencv4ios] add? — There’s not only an [opencv4nodejs] but also an [mode-opencv], I guess they’re the same too?

Comment: I totally agree. I suggest you make a new post, tag it with [tag:burninate-request] and make a list of which tags should go. Then write an answer to that post that explains how posts with these tags should be retaged (for example: [tag:opencv-ios] -> [tag:ios] [tag:opencv]).

Comment: After a few months: Is there an actual burnination process on `cv2` and/or `opencv-python`? I'd like to edit the tag wiki of both following the way of the [`excel-vba`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel-vba) tag, including a link to this question, so that editing questions in that way is a bit more "documented".

Comment: @Hans: no, there is not. Today I’ll try to write an actual [burninate-request] post as suggested above.

Comment: @Hans: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/385792/lets-close-down-these-opencv-tags

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just to formulate a full answer along the lines that have been mentioned in comments: I agree that [opencv-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opencv-python)/[cv2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cv2) are needless, instead questions should be tagged with [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) + [opencv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opencv) and the two tags in question should be burninated.

As I see it, this could be performed fairly easily by

1. first tagging [these questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bopencv-python%5D+or+%5Bcv2%5D+-%5Bpython%5D+is%3Aq&mixed=0) with [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) (the ones that aren't tagged as such already; 207 questions as of the time of posting this)
2. then synonymizing both [cv2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cv2) and [opencv-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opencv-python) into [opencv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opencv).

Comment: This is likely the way to go. But I see [151 tagged cv2, not python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cv2+-python), and [56 tagged opencv-python, not python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opencv-python+-python).

Comment: @CrisLuengo thanks, you're right. Switching to questions in the filter removed the "or" from between the tags :/ Let me update accordingly.

Comment: Great courage to fix this (remove both), I will help to edit! However remember it as I continue to post about angular... :)