# Let's close down these [opencv*] tags

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

There are many interfaces to the [OpenCV](http://opencv.org/) computer vision library. We have the generic [opencv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opencv) (50628 questions), as well as some version-specific tags, and then these:

[cv2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cv2) × 801 (this is the Python interface) 
[opencv4android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opencv4android) × 514 (for Android) 
[opencvsharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opencvsharp) × 166 (for C#) 
[opencv-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opencv-python) × 155 (this is also the Python interface) 
[opencvdotnet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opencvdotnet) × 49 (for .NET) 
[opencv4ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opencv4ios) × 9 (for iOS) 
[opencv4nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opencv4nodejs) × 6 (Node.js) 
[node-opencv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/node-opencv) × 5 (also Node.js)

As far as I know, none of these interfaces do anything special. They just make the OpenCV functions available on different platforms or from different languages.

Say I am using Python and OpenCV. I could tag with [opencv-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opencv-python), but I need to add [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) as well (at the least to get proper syntax highlighting). In this case, what does [opencv-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opencv-python) (or [cv2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cv2)) add over [opencv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opencv)? It just makes it more difficult to find questions related to OpenCV.

So I suggest we get rid of all of these tags.

Note that there are, for example, 12,779 questions tagged [opencv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opencv) and [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python), vs 801 tagged [cv2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cv2) and 155 tagged [opencv-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opencv-python). That is, these language-specific tags are used relatively infrequently.

---

These are the numbers of questions with each of these tags and no [opencv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opencv):

[cv2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cv2+-opencv) × 430 (this is the Python interface) 
[opencv4android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opencv4android+-opencv) × 143 
[opencvsharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opencvsharp+-opencv) × 64 
[opencv-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opencv-python+-opencv) × 64 
[opencvdotnet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opencvdotnet+-opencv) × 6 
[opencv4ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opencv4ios+-opencv) × <strike>2</strike> 0 
[opencv4nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opencv4nodejs+-opencv) × <strike>3</strike> 0 
[node-opencv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/node-opencv+-opencv) × 0

As you can see, *most* people use both tags. The clear outlier here is [cv2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cv2), for which half of the cases there is no [opencv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opencv). In Python, one imports the OpenCV library by importing `cv2`. [cv2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cv2) should be aliased to [opencv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opencv), as per [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/380810/7328782).

The other tags should all be burninated.

Comment: What do you think about the many opencv-versionXX tags? They need probably to be reorganized as well

Comment: @Miki: I don’t see the need for a separate tag for version 3.1 and 3.2, etc. But it makes sense to distinguish the major versions maybe. I haven’t run into the version-specific tags as much as the [cv2] tag, which started this issue for me.

Comment: What about [tag:emgucv] tag. I just noticed when looking at some random questions.

Comment: @Luuklag I always had the feeling, EmguCV is "more" than just a "simple" OpenCV wrapper (cf. [EmguCV's wiki: Architecture Overview](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page#Architecture_Overview)). Although [they recommend using `Mat`](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Working_with_Images#Emgu_CV_3.x), their `Image` class still seems to be widely used. After browsing some `emgucv` questions, one might get the impression, that EmguCV is perceived as some kind of stand-alone product, at least to a certain amount. So, I personally would keep the tag. Cross-tagging `opencv` can still be done.

Comment: @HansHirse Heck If you agree that EmguCV should still be a tag on the basis of `Image`, then you might as well keep a lot of the language version tags, at least when it comes to python, matrix operations are done through `numpy` instead of opencv, copying is done through `numpy` an `python`, and IO doesn't quite work the same as in C++, opencv provides a different serialization API that looks similar but is undocumented and has some large differences.

Comment: @HansHirse: I want to be a bit more careful with JavaCV, as that is a [separate project](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv) and not part of the OpenCV code base.

Comment: @Cris The current wiki excerpt says _Note that JavaCV is now superseded by an official OpenCV Java API._ But, yes, I agree, should better be kept. The mentioned sentence should then be modified to prevent possible confusion with the "official" Java API.

Comment: @CrisLuengo What do you think about the [`opencv-drawcontour`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opencv-drawcontour) tag? I feel its not needed.

Comment: @JeruLuke There's also the [tag:opencv-contour], which says "THIS TAG IS PENDING REMOVAL. Instead, please use [opencv] and [contour] tags." I can edit the [tag:opencv-drawcontour] in the same way. I can't imagine we need a tag for each OpenCV function.

Comment: CMs: See (the second) point 1 [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/385804/6296561); the listed tags need to have [opencv] added to all questions without it, and it'd be preferable for this to happen via CM magic rather than manually

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine: Looking at the list of tags now, it seems like only `opencv4android` and `cv2` still exist. (And `opencv-python` seems to have been added as a synonym of `opencv`, but not merged into it yet.) Is that correct? Are those the only tags where our help is still needed?

Comment: @V2Blast That seems to be the case. For the [cv2] posts, add tag [python] if it’s not already there, then make [cv2] synonymous with [opencv]. For [opencv4android] you should add [android], then make synonymous with [opencv]. Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At this time in 2023, only [opencv4android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opencv4android) and [cv2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cv2) still had questions associated with them. I updated both sets of questions to include the tech tag ([android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) and [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) respectively) as well as [opencv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opencv).

I also set up synonyms from those + other tech-specific opencv tags in the question over to [opencv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opencv), and merged [opencv-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opencv-python) into [opencv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opencv) (after adding [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) where needed).

I goofed [opencv4android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opencv4android) a little and merged it into [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) at first. This has been corrected and it's now a synonym of opencv, but the unfortunate side-effect is that folks who had watched or ignored the original tag had their preferences remapped to [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android). This may or may not be a bad thing, but either way I don't have a way to correct it, so all I can do is apologize if you're in that boat. Sorry!

With all that said, please let me know if anything else needs to be adjusted here.

Answer (score 46):

Please don't do this manually.

Splitting one tag into two different tags is a very easy swoosh of the hand procedure for CMs. Doing this manually is not a good way because:

1. It is pointless extra work.
2. You bump very old and forgotten posts to the main page.
3. You set a precedent that manually doing this is the only way to handle tag splits.

What we need to do here is:

1. For each of these tags, automatically add the [opencv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opencv) tag. We need a community manager for this.
2. Merge each of these tags to the programming language tag. We need a moderator for this.

Both of these are simple one minute tasks, which would result in a least intrusive way of doing the same.

Comment: I had no idea this was possible, this is of course the way to go. I would intuitively do it the other way around, adding the language tag, then merging to [opencv], but I guess it doesn't matter since the end result is the same. What happens when the CM tries to add [opencv] to a question that already has 5 tags? (just mirroring [the question I got earlier today](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/385792/lets-close-down-these-opencv-tags/385804#comment701690_385793))

Comment: @CrisLuengo, the tag won't be added. However, I don't quite see many questions that have this issue.

Comment: @CrisLuengo if Shog/etc can do 95% of the job with an easy button, the residual task is much easier to handle manually.

Comment: @Dan: I agree. So there should be another step in between 1 and 2: manually fix the few posts where the [opencv] tag wasn't added.

Comment: I'm sorry for my possibly naive (Meta) newbie question, but: How does this now progress? Do we just wait for a community manager to do the "easy" task or is there some kind of additional request needed? As stated in my [other comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/380775/the-tags-cv2-and-opencv-python-mean-the-same-thing?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment701532_380775) and in my answer, I would like to edit the tag wikis to prevent people to further use the tags in question. Any objections?

Comment: I'll contact a CM after a few days and get this done, @HansHirse

Comment: Was this ever done? I still see [tag:cv2] as "pending removal".

Comment: Can we get a status update on this, please?

Comment: The CM who was involved with the cleanups was fired a couple of years back, @beaker. So there's no update.

Comment: @BhargavRao Thanks. I was aware of the firing, but was not aware that there was nobody else capable of cleaning up the tags.

Comment: @beaker I started doing the cleanup manually during my spare time. `cv2` and `opencv-contour` tags are my focus.

Comment: @BhargavRao What do you think about the [`opencv-drawcontour`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opencv-drawcontour) tag? I feel its not needed too.

Comment: Hey @JeruLuke, I'm no longer a mod here at SO, so do post your comment as a new meta question instead. :)

Comment: if no CM shows up to fix this, I think I'll eventually have to write a greasemonkey user script...

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz, I'd rather let the CMs do it. Worst case, you can post another meta question asking why there has been no action yet.

Comment: @BhargavRao That would be great, if it actually happened -- but 5 more months have passed, and we're still getting more questions tagged with this (because why bother read the description of the tag). And I totally understand that CM's likely have more important things to worry about. Just that waiting for it to happen seems rather futile.

Comment: I'd ping a mod in chat and try to bring it to their attention, @DanMašek. Looks like Zoe has been actively involved in burnination of late

Comment: @BhargavRao Fair enough, I'll give that a shot. However I'm having a trouble finding anything seemingly relevant at https://chat.stackoverflow.com. Could you, please, point me in the right direction?

Comment: @DanMašek you can check this room out.  https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244740/burnination-hq

Answer (score 12):

Beside the interface specific tags, there are several other opencv* tags, which I personally would like to see to be vanished, too.

First of all, as Miki also pointed out in his comment, there are version specific tags, namely:

- [opencv3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opencv3.0) 2045 questions in total, 922 without additional [opencv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opencv)
- [opencv3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opencv3.1) 363 questions in total, 131 without additional [opencv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opencv)
- [opencv3.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opencv3.2) 44 questions in total, 17 without additional [opencv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opencv)
- [opencv3.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opencv3.3) 54 questions in total, 26 without additional [opencv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opencv)
- [opencv4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opencv4) 39 questions in total, 18 without additional [opencv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opencv)

**Idea #1**

Get rid of all version specific tags (my personal favourite), and request people to state the used OpenCV version in their question, e.g. by adding an appropriate note in the tag wiki - cf. [matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/matlab): *When using this tag, please mention the MATLAB release you're working with (e.g. R2017a).*

Most people already post the OpenCV version they use - or at least you can guess from their error logs.

**Idea #2**

Keep major version tags, like [opencv2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opencv2) (might again lead to confusion with [cv2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cv2)), [opencv3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opencv3), [opencv4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opencv4). [OpenCV is still maintained for versions 2.4.x, 3.4.x, and 4.x.](https://opencv.org/releases)

I personally couldn't make clear guidelines, how to distinguish between the major versions. OpenCV 4.x no longer has C API support, but OpenCV 2.4.x and 3.4.x have - ok. Some (Python) bindings have changed between 3.4.x and 4.x (most prominent one `findContours`, so many questions on that) - ok. But what else?

From my point of view, most "version specific" questions will go into the direction of underlying implementations, like "what algorithm is used for finding contours?". (That actually changed between (major) versions, and it had quite an impact on our products.) But, these questions can only be answered by deep-diving into the source code, and will/should be answered as that, since those changes aren't covered in the documentation either.

---

Second, there are tags like [opencv-contour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opencv-contour) (356 questions, 37 without [opencv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opencv)) or [opencv-drawcontour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opencv-drawcontour) (29 questions, 5 without [opencv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opencv)) - and a few more.

Please, just let's kill them. They don't add any value. Some of them don't even have any watchers.

---

Last point would be [opencv-contrib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opencv-contrib) (49 questions, 7 without [opencv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opencv)). Some implementations (e.g. SURF, SIFT) moved from the main opencv repo to opencv-contrib between major versions due to IP reasons, but I guess questions on SURF, SIFT, etc. will still be flagged [opencv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opencv). So, maybe just get rid of [opencv-contrib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opencv-contrib), too.

---

As you might noticed, my opinion on that topic is: One [opencv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opencv) to rule them all.

Comment: OpenCV Changes the public API every major version change. This has major consequences for C++ users. Headers are split up in different versions, classes get moved around, dependencies change.   Lots of stuff happens, so much so that answers become *absolutely unusable* past major versions because you can't even figure out what the includes are anymore.  Try updating large libraries that use opencv from OpenCV2.x to OpenCV3.x and see what happens.  These changes also cascade to different languages.  Python has had its interface changed so drastically you use numpy arrays instead of cv.mat

Comment: @opa I once migrated a large, productive image processing library from 2.4.x to 3.x.x in C++, basically to get rid of `IplImage` and the C API. (This library uses a lot of different functions from OpenCV, basic and more special ones; it's far away from being simple.) Of course, it was a lot of (also manual) work, but most of the code still worked perfectly fine. I later migrated the same library to OpenCV 4.x.x, and the difference regarding API changes was marginal! So, from my point, the 2.4.x vs. 3.x.x issue is more a C API vs. C++ API. Plus, I don't see a 3.x.x vs. 4.x.x issue.

Comment: [tag:opencv-contrib] is now an alias for [tag:opencv]. I don’t know when the alias was made, but it’s there now.

Answer (score 6):

For all of these tags, the process could be as follows (see [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/380810/7328782)):

1. Add the relevant language/platform tag to those questions that don't already have it.
2. Rename (or synonymize) the tag to [opencv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opencv).

The number of these tags to add are:

[cv2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cv2+-python) × 171
[opencv4android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opencv4android+-android) × 120
[opencvsharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opencvsharp+-c%23) × 52
[opencv-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opencv-python+-python) × 69
[opencvdotnet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opencvdotnet+-.net) × 48
[opencv4ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opencv4ios+-ios) × <strike>1</strike> 0
[opencv4nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opencv4nodejs+-nodejs) × <strike>1</strike> 0
[node-opencv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/node-opencv+-nodejs) × <strike>1</strike> 0

The bottom three tags in the list are easily taken care of, I will do this right away.

Comment: Have you checked whether adding the language/platform tag will push some questions over the 5-tag limit?

Comment: @dbc I have not looked at **all** of these questions, but most already have either the platform tag or the OpenCV tag, in addition to the tag in question. In these cases there is no need for an additional tag. I have not seen many questions that have neither of these two tags. I will do a search for those tonight, and see how many of them have 5 tags. I can’t imagine that to r a huge problem. Do note that most OpenCV questions are already tagged in the way I propose, not using the platform/language-specific OpenCV tag.

Comment: Yeah, I agree, it's very unlikely to be a problem in practice.  My question was really intended as a "crossing-every-t" issue.

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56412418/) is a quite recent question with five tags, one of them being `cv2`, but neither `opencv` nor `python` are tagged. Basically, this question is the reason, why I asked for an update in Cris' other meta post.

Comment: @Hans, I've fixed the tags in that question. More often than not, when there are 5 tags, there are some irrelevant ones. In this case, the question is not about computing a histogram, even if that is the ultimate goal of the asker. Also, people tend to use [image] where they should be using [image-processing]. Read the tag excerpts if you are wondering why I say this. -- But yes, your point is clear: there are questions with 5 tags that need manual intervention to make a decision about which tag to remove.

Answer (score 0):

I very much disagree that "none of these interfaces do anything special".  At least with Python, some of the I/O API functionality looks nothing like the C++ functionality, and due to OpenCV's poor public documentation in general, but also specifically towards these interfaces, it made questions like my own self answered,

[How can I read/write a matrix from a persistent XML/YAML file in OpenCV 3 with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44056880/how-to-read-write-a-matrix-from-a-persistent-xml-yaml-file-in-opencv-3-with-pyth/44056881#44056881)

necessary in order to figure out how you would do the same exact thing in different languages.  Note that OpenCV 2 was even more estranged from C++ in how it did things with matrix serialization in Python.

You'll also notice that much of the OpenCV API gets replaced by [NumPy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NumPy) and Python's own facilities in non obvious ways, especially if you are looking at the much more prominent and support C++ documentation

Examples:

- You don't make OpenCV mats in Python, you make NumPy arrays now for the most part, this is not at all like C++ OpenCV. https://stackoverflow.com/a/37185722/2036035
- You don't clone an image with cv::Mat::clone() or copy(), you use Python's facilities or NumPy's. *[Clone an image in cv2 Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16533078/clone-an-image-in-cv2-python)*

There are a lot of questions that have and can be asked about OpenCV that only apply to the Python interface.  Bottom line, **you can be an expert in the C++ API and not in the Python interface and vice versa**.

I'm not sure whether it is enough to tag both Python and OpenCV C++ differently (I didn't use a Python specific tag on my question), but there definitely is something to the idea that OpenCV Python and OpenCV C++ *are different*.

Comment: ...but your answer in that question supports the opposite point of view from what you say here: "the current python wrapper for opencv looks much more like the c++ version". Yes, you use `numpy.array` in Python and `cv::Mat` in C++. I think that is perfectly covered by adding [python] to the question. The bulk of OpenCV, all the library functions, have but a thin wrapper to make them available in Python. If you know how to use an OpenCV function in C++, you can give advice on how to use it in Python, C#, etc. I know because I've done this. (1/2)

Comment: (2/2) If you know how to solve a computer vision problem with OpenCV in C++, you can explain how to do it to someone using OpenCV in Python. By tagging a question as [cv2], you might be missing the expertise of a lot of people following the [opencv] tag but not the [cv2] tag. This is my main concern with this suggestion.

Comment: I agree with @Cris. Coming from OpenCV C++ myself, I had no problem to understand any OpenCV Python question. I could provide information on how to solve the problem just by pointing out the correct functions, which (till now) have been all covered by the documentation. I then started learning Python with the help of OpenCV(!), just because(!) it "feels" nearly the same. I personally don't see any issue in `cv::Mat` vs. numpy arrays, since the proper use is also covered by the documentation. In the end, what would be your suggestion regarding the many opencv tags?

Answer (score -2):

Basing this action on the observation that language-specific interfaces add nothing special misses a significant pattern that affects Python users.

On a cycle that corresponds to the academic year, there's an upswell in "Help! I can't get cv2 installed!" posts from computer science students. And when "how to do a neat thing with a Raspberry Pi camera" articles are published, there are off-season peaks.

These posts have nothing directly to do with OpenCV, and everything to do with the shifting Python ecosystem and platform vagaries (Python versions, [pip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pip_%28package_manager%29), [Anaconda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anaconda_(Python_distribution)), [virtualenv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv), [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv), etc.). As long as Python remains a popular teaching language, and computer vision stays a thing, this cycle will continue. So why mix this in with API questions? It's clutter.

For installation problems, keeping the [cv2] tag and retagging installation issues to move them from [opencv] to [cv2] (and conversely, retagging OpenCV API posts to move them out of [cv2]) doesn't seem unreasonable. I hang out on both tags, and would be happy to retag if this is something we can agree on.

Comment: I share your sentiment about the "eternal september" problem and desire to keep these pleb issues away from the professionals... however "cv2" is a terrible anachronism and an accident of history that needs to be disappeared. the "raspberry-pi" tag flags one half of those and a selection of "pip/conda/anaconda" mostly flags the rest.

Comment: Accident of history or not, it's history. Keeping Python install questions separate from API usage questions would be, I believe, a better experience for both groups.

Comment: Compared to the amount of crap that flows in on daily basis in the `opencv` tag, the installation questions are a rather insignificant minority. Furthermore, the people asking those questions aren't likely to read the tag descriptions anyway..

Comment: (The [tag wiki for pyenv](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pyenv/info) is plagiarised [from GitHub](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv).)